# Execute file in another directory

Tags: c++, windows

Consider the following:

I have a c++ program in `C:\Documents\myProgram.exe`
With this code in it:
    `system("start C:\\somefolder\\start.bat");`

That will start the target file (start.bat) in `C:\Documents\` instead of `C:\somefolder\'.

My question is, how do I execute the file in it's own directory instead of `myProgram`'s directory?

In theory this is what I want to accomplish using c++:
    `cd C:\somefolder\`,
    `start start.bat`

Comment: You just have to set the working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can do one of two things (that I found).

**A)** You can use chdir() in unistd.h; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html

*or*

**B)** You can  use something called the *File System Interface*, from the GNU library, for more advanced stuff; see http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-System-Interface.html#File-System-Interface.

Anyway, best of luck, I hope you find something that will work!

Comment: I used your solution A for simplicity and it worked flawless! Thank you!

Comment: Since this is tagged Windows: the native API is [`SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That is true, but my option 'A' is still easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on windows anyway, use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can set more things and launch even documents, links etc.